# Connecting to transaction server sockets

Tags: server

How can i connect to a transaction server socket. I want to get updates when ever a new transaction happens.

Answer (score 2):

There is an api endpoint for transactions available here.

https://www.stellar.org/laboratory/#explorer?resource=transactions&endpoint=all&values=eyJzdHJlYW1pbmciOnRydWV9&network=test

You are able to have it act like a socket by using the Server-Sent Events (streaming) mode that is an option at the bottom.

Notice how it changes the URL, and replicate that in your code.

Answer (score 2):

The best way is using the SDK in streaming mode. For all transactions:

```
var channel = server.transactions()
  .forAccount(address)
  .cursor('now')
  .stream({
    onmessage: function(tx) { do something with tx },
    onerror: function(error) { log it }
  });
```

For payments only:

```
var channel = server.payments()
  .forAccount(address)
  .cursor('now')
  .stream({
    onmessage: function(payment) { do something with payment },
    onerror: function(error) { log it }
  });
```

To close the channel simply call itself as a method `channel()`

Ref https://www.stellar.org/developers/js-stellar-sdk/reference/